# How to reset the database after each test unit function?

Tags: java, sql, spring, unit-testing, junit5

I have a test class with junit5.
My production program uses MySQL database. with some initial data.
how can I reset my database after each test function call?
Should I use spring ?

here is my Test Class:

class ATMTest {

```
private ATM atm;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    //TODO: initialize the atm here
    atm = new ATMClass();
}

@Test
void givenAccountNumberThatDoesNotExist_whenWithdraw_thenShouldThrowException() {
    Assertions.assertThrows(AccountNotFoundException.class,
            () -> atm.withdraw("14141414141", new BigDecimal("120.0")));
}


@Test
void givenValidAccountNumber_whenWithdrawAmountLargerThanTheAccountBalance_thenShouldThrowException() {
    Assertions.assertThrows(InsufficientFundsException.class,
            () -> atm.withdraw("123456789", new BigDecimal("20000.0")));
}

@Disabled
@Test
void whenWithdrawAmountLargerThanWhatInMachine_thenShouldThrowException() {
    atm.withdraw("123456789", new BigDecimal("1000.0"));
    atm.withdraw("111111111", new BigDecimal("1000.0"));

    Assertions.assertThrows(NotEnoughMoneyInATMException.class,
            () -> atm.withdraw("444444444", new BigDecimal("500.0")));
}


@Test
void whenWithdraw_thenSumOfReceivedBanknotesShouldEqualRequestedAmount() {
    BigDecimal requestedAmount = new BigDecimal(700);
    List<Banknote> receivedBanknotes = atm.withdraw("111111111", requestedAmount);

    BigDecimal sumOfAllBanknotes = receivedBanknotes.stream().map(Banknote::getValue).reduce(BigDecimal::add).orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);

    Assertions.assertEquals(sumOfAllBanknotes.compareTo(requestedAmount), 0);
}


@Test
void givenAllFundsInAccountAreWithdrwan_whenWithdraw_shouldThrowException() {
    atm.withdraw("222222222", new BigDecimal("500"));
    atm.withdraw("222222222", new BigDecimal("500"));

    Assertions.assertThrows(InsufficientFundsException.class,
            () -> atm.withdraw("222222222", new BigDecimal("500")));
}
```

}

Each test function needs to use the initial state of the data.

Comment: Why are you using a live database for unit tests?

Comment: Use container with database installed in it.

Comment: You can use an in-memory database like h2 else have a tearDown() with AfterEach or After annotation wherein you will add logic to revert any insert/update etc that happened during test runs.

Comment: You might want to learn about [schema migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) tools such as Flyway, Liquibase, and others.

Comment: you could setup the initial data every time to ensure consistency.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of unit testing is to isolate each part of the program and show that the individual parts are correct.
So, instead of using live database all you have to do is provide some *mocks* or *stubs* (With [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/), for example) that simulate returning values from the database.

Otherwise what you are doing is called integration testing.

Answering the question, create basic class with @BeforeEach. There you can implement truncating all tables. In this way, before each @Test method you can set up all data you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do Integration Tests (not Unit tests) where you want to have the database reset to a known state, I would suggest employing a 3rd party library such as DbUnit. (http://dbunit.sourceforge.net)

You could also roll your own if the project is small and "setting it up" isn't that hard.